# Finding the normals of an equation based on their parametric representation

Tags: calculus, parametric

A curve is defined parametrically by the equations

$$
x = t^3 - 6t + 4, y = t - 3 + \frac{2}{t}
$$

The first question, which I've partially solved, was to find the equations of the normals to the curve at the points where the curve meets the x-axis. The next step is to find the coordinates of their point of intersection.

I've already found one normal:

$$
0 = t^3 - 6t + 4 \\
0 = (t-2)(t^2+2t-2) \
$$

So either $t=2$ or $t^2+2t-2 = 0$. How do you take the latter equation and find the second value of $t$? Next we need to find the gradient:

$$\begin{align}
\frac{dy}{dx} & = \frac{dy}{dt} \times \frac{dt}{dx} \\
\frac{dy}{dt} & = 1 - \frac{2}{t^2} \\ 
\frac{dt}{dx} & = \frac{1}{3t^2-6} 
\end{align}$$

Taking $t = 2$, then:

$$
\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{1}{2} \times \frac{1}{6} = \frac{1}{12}
$$

And so the line of the normal will be $y + 12x = 0$. But I can't find the other normal equation (listed as $y+3x+3=0$). How do I find it?

Comment: $(t+1)^2-1-2=0\implies (t+1)^2=3\implies t=1\pm \sqrt 3$

Comment: @Semsem yeah, I thought that - but I struggled with the substitution

Comment: I will do id as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Note*** To meet x-axis put $y=0$ not $x$ and hence $t=1,2$

The gradient is
$$y'=\frac{t^2-2}{t^2}*\frac{1}{3(t^2-2)}=\frac{1}{3t^2}$$
At $t=1,2$ 
$$y'=\frac13\implies slope=-3\\y'=\frac1{12}\implies slope=-12$$